# javascript getattribute issues IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i m using getattribute in javascript and its not working in IE 11. Is there any equivalent for getattribute. below is my code.

code :-

```
var innerFrames = currentRow.all.tags("iframe");

if(innerFrames.length > 0)
{
  var currentFrame = innerFrames[0];
  var frmID = currentFrame.getAttribute("id");
  var ownerID = currentFrame.getAttribute("displayID");
}
var sGroupCaption = (currentFrame.getAttribute("Caption") == null) ? "" : currentFrame.getAttribute("Caption");

if (currentFrame.getAttribute("isEmpty")!= null){ }

    var Type = (currentFrame.getAttribute("displayType") == null) ? "" : currentFrame.getAttribute("displayType");
```

pls suggest with what i can replcae this getattribute in javscript

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access in property like this:

- **currentFrame.myProperty**
- **currentFrame["myProperty"]**

Comment: hi, so you mean var ownerID = currentFrame.getAttribute("displayID"); can be written as var ownerID = currentFrame.["displayID"]; is this correct what u r saying. and  (currentFrame.getAttribute("Caption") == null) can written as  (currentFrame["Caption"] == null) ?

Comment: If you want access to displayID attribute ... var ownerID = currentFrame.displayID

Comment: for (currentFrame.getAttribute("Caption") == null) can be written like (currentFrame.Caption == null) is it correct ?

Comment: Right, but try yourself before ask this question last time :-)

Comment: how about this  if (currentFrame.getAttribute("isEmpty")!= null) how to do this

Comment: If "isEmpty" is an attribute, processing is same. If doesn't work , be sure your "currentFrame" node exist.

Comment: so for this one  if (currentFrame.getAttribute("isEmpty")!= null) i can write like this  if (currentFrame != null) ?

Comment: You don't understand. My previously comment talk to properties access, but if you test "currentFrame != null" , condition check if  currentFrame node is different to null. Conseil for you, take time to learn base of  javascript and you find your answers alone :-)